# ZF2 Modules in Subfolders

Tags: module, zend-framework2, subdirectory

due to a large project which will be realised in ZF2, I came across the following problem and I seem to misunderstand the handling of namepaces.

The project will have a lot of modules of similar groups. I will have 4 groups (A, B, C, D) and all modules in group A will deal with input for example. In order to make sure, that we do not end up with a folder containing 200 modules, we want to group the ones that belong together for reasons of cleanliness.

So basically we wish for the following structure:

```
/config
/module
  /MainApplication <- accesses all modules
  /groupA
    /Module1
    /Module2
  /groupB
    /Module3
    /Module4
...
```

I already adjusted the namespace to `groupA\Module1`, adjusted the routes accordingly and all the paths seem to be correct and yet I get errors saying that for example the template files cannot be accessed.

Can you give me a hint what you would have to pay attention to when you move a model from `/modules/module1` to `/modules/subfolder/module1`.

#### What I tried

```
Changed all namespaces to: -------------------------------------------
    groupa\module1[\Controller]; 

/config/application.php: ---------------------------------------------
...
    'modules' => array(
        'groupa\module1',
    ),
...

/module/groupa/Module.php: -------------------------------------------
...
    'route'    => '/',
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => 'groupa\module1\Controller\Index',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ),
...
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'groupa\module1\Controller\Index' => 'groupa\module1\Controller\IndexController'
```

Currently, the module is not supposed to do much. Just showing the index.phtml template. The error I get is the following:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\View\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "groupa/index/index"; 

resolver could not resolve to a file' in /Users/xxx/Sites/zf2helloworld/vendor/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php:461 

Stack trace: 
#0 /Users/xxx/Sites/zf2helloworld/vendor/Zend/View/View.php(203): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) 
#1 /Users/xxx/Sites/zf2helloworld/vendor/Zend/View/View.php(231): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) 
#2 /Users/xxx/Sites/zf2helloworld/vendor/Zend/View/View.php(196): Zend\View\View->renderChildren(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) 
#3 /Users/xxx/Sites/zf2helloworld/vendor/Zend/Mvc/View/Http/DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(128): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel)) 
#4 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) 
#5 /Users/xxx/Sites/zf2helloworld/vendor/Zend/EventManager/Ev in /Users/xxx/Sites/zf2helloworld/vendor/Zend/View/Renderer/PhpRenderer.php on line 461
```

Am I missing the obvious? Why can the template not be found? I echoed back the `'template_path_stack'` and it seems to be correct:

```
/Users/xxx/Sites/zf2helloworld/module/groupa/module1/view
```

I am aware of the reusability of modules and such. We would still love to group modules that belong together into the same folder and preferably access them via the proper URL (groupname/module).

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as per [PSR-0 standard](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) your classnames must have the following structure: `\<Vendor Name>\(<Namespace>\)*<Class Name>`.
Meaning that your module name should be `<Vendor Name>\<Module\Name>`

As for template name, by default FQCN of controller is converted to template like this `First namespace/controller class name/controller action name`
Meaning your `Groupa\Module1\Controller\IndexController` controller will give you template name `groupa/index/index`(and not `groupa/module1/index/index` as you might expect) which will be resolved to file `groupa/index/index.phtml` in paths defined in `template_path_stack`

This is default behaviour and it cannot be changed without backwards compatibility break. To mitigate that since zf2.3 there is new setting that will allow you to use modules the way you want.
It is `controller_map` under `view_manager` config section.

How to use that you can read here:
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/5670

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'controller_map' => array(
        // Groupa\Module1\Controller\IndexController -> groupa\module1\index\index
        // -> module/Groupa/Module1/view/groupa/module1/index/index.phtml
        'Groupa\Module1' => true,
    ),
);
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your brilliant answer, I guess I'm lucky that you added this feature! However, although the template path gets altered, the template still cannot be loaded: `Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "group/hello-world/index/index"; resolver could not resolve to a file` (The file to be resolved it: `/module/group/HelloWorld/view/hello-world/index/index.phtml`)

Comment: @user2033511 It tells you what it expects! Right there with template name it can't find. `/module/group/HelloWorld/view/group/hello-world/index/index.phtml`

Comment: unfortunately it does not. Thats what I typed to show you my folder structure! Thats where the file is, but the renderer still seems to look at the wrong place!